# Using ImageMagick and PHP IMAP together causes problems

Tags: php, imagemagick, imap

I am developing a PHP script to replace a C# Windows service that reads client emails and converts attachments in whatever format they are in to a standard format.  The IMAP piece works fine until I start converting large documents with ImageMagick, then I start getting errors in any IMAP function that attempts to execute: "Trying to get property of non-object".  Also from that point, a function to save the emails to .eml files begins to save what are essentially empty files and the code to set each email to 'seen' from 'unseen' quits working.

If I skip processing of the emails with the largest attachments everything works fine.

If I run the code commenting out the ImageMagick commands it runs fine, including saving the .eml files and setting 'unseen' to 'seen', so it's something to do with ImageMagick, but I'll be damned if I can figure out what.

I've added $imagick->clear() each time an image is finished converting.

I've added this immediately after creating the $imagick object:
    $imagick->setResourceLimit(imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY, 256);
    $imagick->setResourceLimit(imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP, 256);
    $imagick->setResourceLimit(imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA, 1512);
    $imagick->setResourceLimit(imagick::RESOURCETYPE_FILE, 768);
    $imagick->setResourceLimit(imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK, -1);

Any ideas, anyone?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does it take? Is the IMAP connection timing out?

Comment: I just ran the process against 6 emails, including 2 of the 'problem' emails.  It took 20 minutes to run.  I added these lines to my code to no apparent effect (still displayed same behavior as described in first post):
imap_timeout(IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT, 6000);
imap_timeout(IMAP_READTIMEOUT, 6000);
imap_timeout(IMAP_WRITETIMEOUT, 6000);
My log file has these errors at the end:
0 Unknown: SECURITY PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN (errflg=1)
0 Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2)
0 Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection lost (errflg=2)  (occurs 26 times)

Comment: What server are you running it against?  Some servers will close connections if they are idle.  Specifically, Yahoo's IMAP server will close a connection after 2 minutes of inactivity.  Maybe you should do this processing off line....

Comment: @Max, you're my hero.  I did some additional research and added a periodic execution of imap_ping during image processing and that seems to be taking care of the problem.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I will convert to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IMAP connection is likely timing out. Some servers will close the connection after very short amounts of inactivity, as low as 2 minutes for Yahoo.